# PowerBI Report Tooltip Pages not filtering correctly

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I created a report tooltip page and it is being displayed on my visual. However, it isn't displaying the results I'd expect it to display. How do I force the tooltip to apply the same filtering as is applied to the visual? Eg, in my visual the value is 1 event, however when I hover over number one, a list of ALL events is displayed in the tooltip. How do I ensure that correct filtering is applied? Note: my visual is a matrix made up of multiple measures as rows and multiple columns (using calculated groups).

Also, since my tooltip is just a table displaying a long list of results, when I try to hover over the tooltip and scroll down the list it doesn't allow me to do that. I cannot seem to click on the tooltip. What am I missing here?